# Scraping a list of urls using beautifulsoup and convert data to csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python. Questions below:

1. I have a list of urls I want to scrape data from. I don't know what is wrong with my code, I am unable to retrieve results from all urls. The code is only scraping the first url and not the rest. How can I successfully scrape data (title, info, description, application) in all urls in the list?
2. If question 1 works, how can I convert the data into a CSV file?

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError

urlList = ["url1","url2","url3"...lists of urls.......]

for url in urlList:
    try:
        html = urlopen(url)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
    except URLError:
        print("error")
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html5lib")
# Scraping
def getTitle():
    for title in soup.find('h2', class_="xx").text:
            print(title)

def getInfo():
   for info in soup.find('ul', class_="j-k-i").text:
        print(info)

def getDescription():
    for description in soup.find('div', class_="b-d").text:
        print(description)

def getApplication():
    for application in soup.find('div', class_="g-b bm-b-30").text:
       print(application)

for soups in soup():
    getTitle()
    getInfo()
    getDescription()
    getApplication()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following kind of approach:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
import csv


def getTitle(soup):
    return soup.find('h2', class_="xx").text

def getInfo(soup):
    return soup.find('ul', class_="j-k-i").text

def getDescription(soup):
    return soup.find('div', class_="b-d").text

def getApplication(soup):
    return soup.find('div', class_="g-b bm-b-30").text

urlList = ["url1","url2","url3"...lists of urls.......]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')  as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Title', 'Info', 'Desc', 'Application'])
    
    for url in urlList:
        try:
            html = urlopen(url)
        except HTTPError as e:
            print(e)
        except URLError:
            print("error")
        else:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html5lib")
            row = [getTitle(soup), getInfo(soup), getDescription(soup), getApplication(soup)]
            print(row)
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This passes the current `soup` to each function to use. Each function now returns the text that is found (previously the for loop was printing a character at a time).

Lastly, Python's `csv` library can be used to easily write a correctly formatted CSV file. It takes a list of values for each row and writes by default a comma separated row in `output.csv`.

Note: not tested as you have not provided any suitable URLs.

Comment: Hello @martin, thanks very much for your response. the terminal output is coming as a single line. see the picture from the link: https://i.postimg.cc/Kjt0vkQG/pythonoutput.png      is there a way  i can have a terminal output like: 1[link    title    info    description application]

Comment: is there a way i can export as csv?

Comment: Your use of a for loop on a string caused it to print a character at a time. A loop is not needed. Python's CSV library can be used to write a list of values as a row in a CSV file. For this to work, you need to return the text from each of your functions.

Comment: How, may you please help me by putting in the script?

Comment: I've already updated the answer, try refreshing

Comment: This is outstanding!!! thanks this is what i wanted.!! thanks @Martin Evans

Comment: Am trying to scrape over 11000 urls, but the script is only scraping upto 59 urls. is there a way i can scrape all the 11000 urls at once?

Comment: Be careful, if you hit a single host too much they can block you. Take a look at the `grequests` package

Comment: Okay thanks @martin